# XSL Transformation for table data

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have some XML that stores column information and row data from a table in the following form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<table>
  <columns>
    <column id="1">
      <name>Date</name>
      <type>Date</type>
    </column>
    <column id="2">
      <name>Name</name>
      <type>String</type>
    </column>
  </columns>
  <rows>
    <row id="1">
      <columns>
        <column id="1">
          <name>Date</name>
          <value>1-Dec-2010</value>
          <localDate>1-Dec-2010 00:00:00 GMT</localDate>
        </column>
        <column id="2">
          <name>Name</name>
          <value>Jim</value>
        </column>
      </columns>
    </row>
    <row id="2">
      <columns>
        <column id="1">
          <name>Date</name>
          <value>2-Dec-2010</value>
          <localDate>2-Dec-2010 00:00:00 GMT</localDate>
        </column>
        <column id="2">
          <name>Name</name>
          <value>Jane</value>
        </column>
      </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
</table>
```

NOTE:  This is a cut down version of my xml.  I have a lot more rows and store a lot more information on each column.

Is it possible to apply an XSL transform that will iterate through each row in the xml and output each column value.  If the column is of type DateTime (as specified in the column information) I want to output the **localDate** text value otherwise I will just output the **value** text value.

I can do a little XSL but I am unsure as to how you would check the different part of the document which would essentially map from the tableModel/rows/row/columns/column to the tableModel/columns/column.

I am essentially outputting this as CSV.  I have code in place to append the column information for each /tableModel/rows/row/columns/column xml but I think this is unnecessary and it makes the xml too large for Netbeans/Visual Studio to handle (around 7MB).

The output I am trying to get is:

```
Date,Name
1-Dec-2010 00:00:00 GMT,Jim
2-Dec-2010 00:00:00 GMT,Jane
```

Many thanks,

Andez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the following produces the described output for your input sample

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="sep" select="','"/>
  <xsl:param name="lf" select="'&#10;'"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="table/columns/column/name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$lf"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="table/rows/row"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="column/name">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rows/row">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="columns/column"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$lf"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row/columns/column[not(localDate)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row/columns/column[localDate]">
    <xsl:value-of select="localDate"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but it does not look at the corresponding column type, it simply outputs the localDate element if that is present. Does that suffice? 
Please also state whether you can use XSLT 2.0 (as implemented by AltovaXML Tools or Saxon 9), that makes such stuff easier.

[edit] I wanted to use a key in match pattern and though that is not allowed in XSLT 1.0 but it seems it works so the following is a better implementation of your requirement:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="sep" select="','"/>
  <xsl:param name="lf" select="'&#10;'"/>

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="table/columns/column" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="table/columns/column/name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$lf"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="table/rows/row"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="column/name">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rows/row">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="columns/column"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$lf"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row/columns/column[not(key('k1', @id)/type = 'Date')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row/columns/column[key('k1', @id)/type = 'Date']">
    <xsl:value-of select="localDate"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Martin.  Thanks for that.  I am currently writing my XSL in M$ Visual Studio 2008 although we are writing the code to produce transforms in Java under Netbeans 6.9.1.  I hate the XML editor in Netbeans.

Comment: Ideally I want to link to the column from the rows as there is other information I will be checking such as formats etc.

Comment: Well with Java you could switch to Saxon 9 and XSLT 2.0 as the XSLT processor. But see my edit, it shows how to use a key to find the referenced column and it works with XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  It works and I can follow it through pretty much.  Only thing that I cannot see is when you have <xsl:apply-templates select="table/rows/row"/>, which template it applies?  Or does it try to apply them all but there would be matches only where the match would return a node?

Comment: The apply-templates select the "row" element children of the "rows" child element of the "table" element for processing with a matching template. There is one matching template, that with match="rows/row" as that matches any "row" elements that are children of a "row" element.

Answer (score 0):

This less verbose but maybe... esoteric stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:key name="kDataType" match="type" use="../@id"/>
    <xsl:template match="value|table/*/*/name">
        <xsl:variable name="vIsDateType"
                      select="key('kDataType',../@id)='Date'"/>
        <xsl:value-of
             select="concat(substring(',',
                                      1 div boolean(../preceding-sibling::*)),
                            self::name,
                            self::value[not($vIsDateType)],
                            ../localDate[$vIsDateType],
                            substring('&#xA;',
                                      1 div not(../following-sibling::*)))"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
Date,Name
1-Dec-2010 00:00:00 GMT,Jim
2-Dec-2010 00:00:00 GMT,Jane
```